# Using jquery to enlarge image on mouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/moragw5/vr6wzuc2/5/)
 This is my code so far

I am looking to enlarge each image separately on mouseover or hover using jquery. I have the backbone of the code I think butit is not fully working yet. I'm a complete newbie to jQuery so trying to understand some articles online has been challenging and this is as close as I can see myself getting after spending an hour working on this problem.

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.j-creative.biz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/primary-colours-300x171.png" id="test" alt="" />
<br>
<img src="http://www.j-creative.biz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/primary-colours-300x171.png" id="test1" alt="" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
$(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
 }, function () {
        $(this).css({ width: auto, height: auto });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });
    }
}, '#test');
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/j9v886qz/2/)

Your answer was missing  `$(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });`

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
$(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
 }, function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });
});
```

[Demo Your Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/j9v886qz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
  $(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
}).mouseleave( function () {
  $(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });
});
```

And you need to have jquery set up in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1mnLwgny/

Answer (score 0):

> **1.**  `auto` is not a variable . put in inverted commas
>
> **2.**  Add JQuery library

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vr6wzuc2/7/)

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
$(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
 }, function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget  to include JQuery in your fiddle.

```
$('#test').hover(function() {
$(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
 }, function () {
        $(this).css({ width: "auto", height: "auto"});
});
```

Working version : 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/vr6wzuc2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work on both images and will enlarge them separately

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
});
```

one more thing, you DEMO does not have jQuery included.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You almost there. Just you forget to include JQuery library.

Include it `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And change JQuery to following:

```
$('img').hover(function() {
$(this).animate({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
 }).mouseleave( function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: "auto", height: "auto" });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr6wzuc2/8/)**